# "Shoot it" in meaning of "say it"- could it be?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Today I asked my friend a riddle. He told me that he knows the answer, then I told him "**shoot it**" in meaning of "**say it**", but later I decided to check it out in the [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shoot) but I didn't find such meaning. Maybe I heard it in the past and that's why I used it, or maybe I didn't use it correctly in context. Is the such meaning to "shoot it"? I used it correctly in context?

Comment: Colloquially, we would just say *shoot*, not *shoot it*. (Although *go for it* would be more common.)

Answer (score 2):

The relevant definition is in the [dictionary you linked to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shoot) (and others I’ve checked). You’re just not saying it exactly right; it’s just “shoot”:

> exclamation UK /ʃuːt/ US /ʃuːt/ informal
>
> used to tell someone that they should speak:
>
> > "Dad, I need to talk to you." "Shoot."

It’s a common enough expression and I don’t think it sounds outdated at all. (For reference, I speak American English.)

Answer (score 1):

No.

You can say "shoot" to mean "ask your question". But in this context there is no object. Implicitly the object is "me" and saying "shoot" is short for "shoot me with your question". In this context it could be extended to mean "shoot me with your answer".

It is not a very common expression, and perhaps a bit dated.